# How do piecewise affine transformation work?

Tags: image-processing

How can piecewise affine transform be used to warp an arbitrary collection of input landmark coordinates to a corresponding set of base coordinates?

Can anyone give any physical examples, the book I am currently reading on image processing dose not seem to give a good explanation, and I can't find any physical example on the internet.

Comment: any relation to mach distribution?